# Working with iframes in Cypress - breaks time travel in runner?

Tags: iframe, cypress

Can someone help here? I'm trying to test with iframes, and following the blog post at https://www.cypress.io/blog/2020/02/12/working-with-iframes-in-cypress/ - and it seems to work. For example, I have a bit of code:

```
cy.get('iframe[name="Framename"]').its('0.contentDocument.body').should('not.be.empty').then(cy.wrap).find('span.colortitle').then((elem) => cy.log(elem.text()))
```

And this successfully logs the span.colortitle element text. However, within the cypress runner, when the test run completes I can see the web page rendered successfully - but as soon as I start clicking through the steps at the end of the run, the iframe container simply shows an empty box with " placeholder for https://[....]" instead of the iframe's contents. when running the test headlessly and capturing video, the iframe is properly rendered - clearly it's working since the cy.log above works - but why is the iframe 'masked' like this in the runner when you use the time travel feature?

Comment: I am not a Cypress expert, but my gut feeling is that iframe is a separate HTML document. There are API limitations what a browser can do for iframes within a web browser.